# how to place a filled shape on a bbox to maks the moving object like placing rectangle using insertObjectAnnotation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I would like to place a mask (image) on a moving object that is extracted using blob analysis.

```
frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', bboxes, labels);
```

I found an example in matlab documentation.  here bbox is the cordinates of moving object. its drawing rectangles around the moving objects in the video using `inserObjectAnnotation()`  function.
like that I want to place a filled in shape in place of rectangle. how can I do that?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The `insertShape` function can draw filled shapes into images.